# WPF: Cannot Get Custom Attached Property to work as a Trigger Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have a class that looks like this:

```
internal class MyClass
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSomethingProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "IsSomething", // property name
                typeof(bool), // property type
                typeof(MyClass), // owner type
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false)
                );

    public static void SetIsSomething(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsSomethingProperty, value);
    }

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(TreeViewItem))]        
    public static bool GetIsSomething(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsSomethingProperty);
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to use this attached property as a trigger property in a control template, like so:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <!-- stuff here omitted for brevity -->
    <Trigger Property="my:MyClass.IsSomething" Value="True">
        <!-- setters for when IsSomething is True -->
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate>
```

(the above control template assumes the proper `xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyAssembly"` where MyAssembly contains MyClass is in the enclosing XAML file)

Here's my trouble: when I do this, it compiles fine.  However, when I try to see this control template in action in the designer, it complains `Cannot find the 'IsSomething' template property on type 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem'.` and the designer won't load.

I've tried the `RegisterAttached` override with `MyClass` as well as `TreeViewItem` as the owner type, neither fixes this.  I've also tried it with and without the `AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType` attribute on `GetIsSomething`.  Does anyone see what the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer as soon as I posted the question.  I'm posting the answer to help anyone who's run into the same issue.  **Mark your class public**.  Not sure if this is by design or not, but it seems they could at least improve the error message here.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Had something like this magically fixed by setting the "startup object" in the project's properties.